# Eliminar � al momento de recorrer filas

Tags: c#, split

Al leer un archivo excel, hay información que contienen guiones `"-"` y al recorrer las filas y llegar a uno que tiene un guion lo muestra como `�`, por lo que al buscar ninguno coincide y no realiza ningún proceso que tengo.

Como que método puedo usar para quitar el guion al momento de leer las filas, o reemplazarlo, algún método efectivo.

intente usar esto  `string[] data = line.Split('-');` pero no resulto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias ayudarte el `Replace()` mientras iteras las lineas

Algo como ser

```
foreach(var line in lineas)
{
    line = line.Replace("-", " ");
}
```

entonces quitas los `-` y le dejas el espacio

[string.Replace(String, String)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_)